# reading html from an inputstream java

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am reading a html file using an inputstream from a java servlet.
But the contents of the original and the read one are in a different format
although when displayed in a web browser they are the same. These are the two
links for the html files 
after reading output
http://www.fileflyer.com/view/gQREGAe
orginal output
http://www.fileflyer.com/view/mWXHVAE
Is there a way to get the original html when reading? why is this happening?
my java code is as follows;

```
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
     String line = null;
     while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
     {
      System.out.println(line);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thank you,
rana.

Comment: what do you mean by different format?

Comment: html code is different. not the output from browser.

Comment: could you paste the code in somethin like pastie.org or pastebin.com. I'm not willing to download random files ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The one in different format (the one named `extracted.html`) is clearly generated by Microsoft Word.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
      xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
      xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word"
      xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
```

Your problem is more in the *source* of the `InputStream`, not in the Java or Servlet side. They do for sure not randomly change the content of the `InputStream` without your intervention.

You seem to be using MS Word as a HTML editor, you should not do that, there it is not for. Rather use a textbased editor like Notepad, Notepad++, Editplus, etc for HTML editing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen both the html files. The extracted.html obviously has more tags/comments/css info that you doesn't seem to be interested. So, the only option you are left with is to use 1 of the below parsers and remove the unnecessary nodes/attributes you doesn't require (or just extract what you need)

1. [Mozilla html parser](http://mozillaparser.sourceforge.net/)
2. [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: hi, I have added an attribute named "template" to the original html code. but it is not represented in the output. do you know why?